# update time continuously on asp.mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I am having a asp.mvc file and in its Site.Master page, I want to update the time continuously.
Here is the code I wrote.

```
<asp:Label ID="DateTimeLabel" runat="server" Text=""><%= DateTime.Now.ToString()%></asp:Label>
```

Can anyone tell me how to change the time continuously(I don't have background code i.e. code behind file)? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why you are using server controls in an asp.net mvc app ...

Answer (score 2):

Whether you're using WebForms or MVC this would probably better done with client side Javascript. See [this article for a how to](http://www.elated.com/articles/creating-a-javascript-clock/). Here's an even [simpler implementation with a running example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock).